# Intel's App Framework footer won't hide

Tags: css, appframework

I have an app and can't get the footer to go away. I can remove all the content from it but there is still space that isn't being used by the content. Also, for some reason the side panel is leaving artifacts. Anybody ever have to deal with this. At first I thought this was an android rendering problem but it shows up in Chrome as well...

[image]

```
<script>
    $.ui.ready( function(){
        console.log('ready');
        $.feat.nativeTouchScroll=false; //Disable native scrolling globally
        $.ui.removeFooterMenu();
    });
</script>
<style>
#navbar {
display:none;
}
</style>
<div id="afui">

    <!--Left Side Menu Navigation bar -->
    <nav>
        <ul class="list">
            <li><a href="#page1" class="icon home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page2" class="icon heart">Favorites</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page3" class="icon chat">Messages</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page4" class="icon user">Profile</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div id="content" style=""> 

    <!--Main View Pages-->
        <div class="panel" title="Events" id="page1" selected="true" data-footer="none">
            <header>
                <a id="menubadge" onclick='$.ui.toggleSideMenu()' class='menuButton' style="float:left !important"></a>
                <h1>Lunch Box</h1>
            </header>
            <p>This is view for first menu item</p>
            <p>
               Content.....
            </p>
        </div>
...some other panels...
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had brought in a css file from the stylebuilder here, http://app-framework-software.intel.com/style2.php, this seems to be the root of the problem. I brought back in the default appframework-2.1.0/build/css/af.ui.css file and then changed the colors directly from that and now I am not having the issue.